# how do I insmod android SPI driver to running ubuntu PC

Tags: android, linux-kernel, spi

I am developing SPI driver on PC ubuntu, for my devkit8000 android.

I saw some example on how to build one.
But it seem like I can build my SPI driver and insmod it into the running kernel.
(here is the link)
http://www.jumpnowtek.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=57&Itemid=62

Current my understanding is point it to my ubuntu's "/lib/modules/..."
This part I managed.
But I am not able to "modprobe omap2_mcspi", which I think is a major component for my SPI driver for DevKit8000.

I hope someone can help me to verify is it true that I can insmod my SPI driver into the running kernel.
If that is possible, when I "make" which should I point to.
And how should I make modprobe appears.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you have cross-compiled your driver on your PC (x86 or x86_64 platform) for your Gumstix board (ARM Cortex- A8- platform) and that you have issued the modprobe command on the Gumstix board.

When you refer to your Ubuntu's /lib/modules, I presume that you mean an Ubuntu OS running on the Gumstix board (just to make sure that you don't try to insmod the module on the PC).

Now it is mandatory that the kernel version number of your module exactly matches the kernel version number of the kernel running on your Gumstix board (exactly means e.g. Linux 2.6.32-whatever-suffix-appended-here). If not, the kernel will reject your module.

Make sure that you have all modules installed the omap2_mcspi depends on.

If none of that was helpful, can you please post the error message the modprobe command throws?